# what hadoop jar do i need to get the WeightAdjuster interface

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, jar, gradle

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.WeightAdjuster
```

and

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.NewJobWeightBooster
```

I've added all the jars I can find on Maven almost. Here's my current build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-core', version: '1.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version: '2.5.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-yarn-common', version: '2.5.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-yarn-server-common', version: '2.5.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-core', version: '2.5.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-common', version: '2.5.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient', version: '2.5.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-app', version: '2.5.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-tools', version: '1.2.1'
}
```

Which jar should I be grabbing? [This link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/fair_scheduler.html) gives a partial description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding every hadoop jar on Maven, I found it:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager', version: '2.5.1'
```